# Scapy WPA2 packet forging

Tags: network, wpa2, packet

Can I use scapy to forge custom packets on WPA2 network? Can I even pack the IEEE 802.11 headers?

Comment: yes, `sendp()` and `srp()` are what you are looking for - it's in the manual: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html

Comment: How different will be things with the WPA2 encryption?

Answer (score 2):

There are several [dot11 classes](http://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/namespacescapy_1_1layers_1_1dot11.html) that are declared to help with low network layers.  However, based on their less than adequate documentation that WEP is the only secure protocol that is *somewhat* supported.  Scapy's manual shows some [WiFi sniffing](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#wireless-sniffing), but doesn't really delve too much into Wireless communication.

All-in-all you'd probably have to hack together a mixed solution of raw data, and some of their classes to do what you want.  Not impossible, but not as easy as spoofing other protocols with Scapy.